# How to apply `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Api")]` with Minimal API in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, minimal-apis, asp.net-minimal-apis

I am trying to to Minimal API in an ASP.NET Core app. I added the following endpoint

```
app.MapPost("api/content", CallbackAsync);
```

The defined the `CallbackAsync` as a static function as the following

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Api")]
private static async Task<IResult> CallbackAsync(
    
    IAuthorizationService authorizationService,
    HttpContext httpContext)
{
    // ...

    return Results.Ok(...);
}
```

Authentication is failing. when I use controller, adding `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Api")]` works but not with Minimal API.

How can I apply `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Api")]` with minimal API?

Comment: Do you have a full [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure authentication middleware explicitly.
UseAuthentication() and UseAuthorization() adds required middlewares to the pipeline.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();

// Add authentication middleware
app.UseAuthentication();

// Add authorization middleware
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapPost("api/content", CallbackAsync);

app.Run();

[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Api")]
private static async Task<IResult> CallbackAsync(
    IAuthorizationService authorizationService,
    HttpContext httpContext)
{
    // ...

    return Results.Ok(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to a standard controller attribute. In Program.cs file,

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer("api");
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder()
  .AddPolicy("api", policy =>
        policy
            .RequireRole("admin")
            .RequireClaim("scope", "api/content"));

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapPost("api/content", (HttpContext context, 
                           IOtherDependency otherDependency, 
                           CallBackAsyncClass callBackAsyncClass) => 
    callBackAsyncClass.CallBackAsync(otherDependency, context))
    .RequireAuthorization("api");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

For additional information this link should be helpful.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/security?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Ensure that any other dependencies that rely on DI are also injected using

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDependency, Dependency>();
```

The DI part should remain the same.

Comment: `RequireAuthorization("api")` is using the `api` policy not the `AuthenticationSchemes`.